# Cannot access to (or find out) main Settings program

Tags: system-settings

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

After removed **Ibus Preferences** & **Input Method** I'm not able to find out the main **Settings** program. There are somethings I have tried:

- Hit **Windows** button on keyboard then find `Settings` (**Settings** not show on search result).
- Click **Power** button on top right screen, then click on **Setting** button.
- Try to **right click** on desktop screen then choose **Change Background**.

But nothing helps.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It is unclear which *Settings* you are trying to open. Usually the system is shipped with GNOME Control Center (`gnome-control-center` command in terminal). If you are trying to open IBus Preferences you can use `ibus-setup` command (part of `ibus` package).

Comment: Hi @N0rbert, my **Settings** is exactly `gnome-control-center` you have mentioned.  I just mention to **Ibus** because after I removed it, I run into this problem.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Reinstall *Settings* (aka `gnome-control-center`) by running

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

in Terminal.

Comment: You are the saviour. Works also for the xfce with compiz installed over default gnome ubuntu installation.